# How to check multiple object properties twice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of nice functions like `filter()`, `hasOwnProperty()` or `indexOf()`, but I don't know how to handle with them in my problem.

First, let me show you my current code:

```
var Lines = [];

// [..] pushing a lot of objects in the Lines Array, now it is like this:
Lines[0] = {line: 'a', x: 2, y: 4, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[1] = {line: 'b', x: 3, y: 4, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[2] = {line: 'c', x: 5, y: 3, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[3] = {line: 'd', x: 1, y: 4, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[4] = {line: 'e', x: 2, y: 4, z: 3, visible: true}//same as Lines[0]
Lines[5] = {line: 'f', x: 6, y: 6, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[6] = {line: 'g', x: 5, y: 7, z: 3, visible: true}
Lines[7] = {line: 'h', x: 3, y: 4, z: 3, visible: true}//same as Lines[1]
//..
```

Now I want to have a function where I can multiple lines where x and y are the same. (in example `index 0 & 4` are the same and 7 and 1 are the same) and set visible to false if there are two lines at the same `x & y` position, otherwise set visible to true.

Now the question: How can I check multiple object properties (x & y have to be the same) in an Array and handle them?

Comment: Would it be an option to perform that check when you're pushing the elements into your `Lines` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var index = {},
    lines = [/* your lines here */];

lines.forEach(function (line) {
    var key = line.x + ':' + line.y;
    line.visible = !(key in index);
    index[key] = true;    
});
```

1. Create an index (an object) that will contain the properties you want to check for uniqueness.
2. In your case, the combination of `x` and `y` will be the unique property (i.e. the `key`). We can use a separated string for that: `line.x + ':' + line.y`. Take care to use a separator that can not naturally occur in `x` and `y`, a colon will do fine for numbers.
3. Go though the lines one by one, check if their `key` already is in the index. If it is, make them invisible and vice versa.
4. Store the key in the index, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

A simple (though not very efficient if the array becomes very large) solution would be to go through the array and check for any duplicates, like so:

```
for (var i=0;i<Lines.length;i++) {
    for (var j=i+1;j<Lines.length;j++) {
        if (Lines[i].x==Lines[j].x&&Lines[i].y==Lines[j].y) {
            Lines[j].visible = false;
            //...and whatever action you want to perform on a duplicate
        }
    }
}
```